# Problems with two object collision

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

I was trying to make a a keyring, so I modelled it and a key.
For the two items I activated the collision and the rigid body as active, but instead of falling together, it seems like the two objects jump in different directions orizontally.

[image]

[image]

The hole of the key was made with a boolean modifier, but I have already applied it.
[image]

Comment: make sure that the Shape of the 2 object is set to Mesh, also apply the Transfoms, put the origins at the geometry, if it still doesn't work you'll need to find another trick

Comment: Perfect, now the problem is that once the object falls on the ground, they never stop bouncing and moving

Comment: Yes rigid body is far from perfect, you could bake the simulation then remove the bad keyframes, or use another method like the rigid body Connect, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I added the file in the question, tell me if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Rigid body physics "doesn't like" complicated geometry. So i replaced your spiral ring with a simple torus, gave that a rigid body, removed it from your spiral and just parented your spiral to the torus.
I applied rotation + scale for all objects, change shape of the box from mesh to box and moved it in edit mode so that it fits inside the shape.
Also i joined the key (there were two objects which made it really unrealistic) gave it a rigid body and mesh as shape.
I removed all collisions because they make no sense in rigid body world because they only have effect on cloth and soft bodies.
I changed friction of all to 1, played a bit with the weights and got:

[image]

[image]

You may want to adapt the torus a bit if you are looking for perfection....i just wanted to show a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix your simulation (I may be wrong but it seems hard to deal with ring type objects) you could bake it: Duplicate your 2 objects in order to keep the rigid body versions somewhere in another collection, select the 2 objects, bake the simulation (*Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*):

[image]

Then in the Timeline, select all the keyframes that you want to remove and remove:

[image]

To make the end of the animation smoother, move some of the remaining keyframes to the right, until it looks good when you play the animation:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't seem to work

Comment: what problem do you meet exactly?